# AngularJS - draggable bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, draggable

I am using an *AngularJS* directive for modals, to make them draggable.

[This](http://embed.plnkr.co/8CHoiN/preview) is the directive.

In the demo, you can clearly see that if you drag it (especially left and right) it is slower than your mouse. I understand why this happens (the JavaScript calculates position relative to it's starting position, so in my 1920x1080 screen it goes from -1200px to 1920px on the x axis). And I understand there is a need to use offset instead of position, but after many tries I failed to make it that.

This is the relevant JavaScript code:

```
element.on('mousedown', function (event) {
  // Prevent default dragging of selected content
  event.preventDefault();
  startX = event.screenX - x;
  startY = event.screenY - y;
  $document.on('mousemove', function mousemove(event) {
      y = event.screenY - startY;
      x = event.screenX - startX;
      element.css({
         top: y + 'px',
         left: x + 'px'
      });
   });
});
```

How can I make it rely on the offset and move together with the mouse and not slower?

Comment: What you're doing wrong, is that you're moving "everything". If you comment out the "mouseup" event, you can see with the devtools, that you're moving the container of the modal window. I'm guessing that you only want to move the inner element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/QxIdGj . I have hardcoded 2 values, which you shouldn't do. Your "mistake" was that you were putting the draggable directive in the wrong element. I added the draggable directive to `<div class="modal-content">` which is what I believe is the element that you want moved.

I also changed your `element.css({` to

```
element.css({
        top: event.clientY - 30 + 'px',
        left: event.clientX - 10 + 'px'
      });
```

It's using .clientX/Y which is the actual position of the mouse, without the need of further calculations.

Comment: The drag you suggest works good and reliable, with one issue: it disregards the place of the drag. (If I try to drag from the middle of the modal header for example, it "jumps" to my mouse coordinates, and is weird.) Is there a way to fix that? I tried to mix what is done in the source code (which takes this in consideration) to your solution, but got an awful experience.